# BASH - Check if a volume is attached to instance without AWS CLI tools

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, device, mount

I'm working on a script that needs to check if volume is attached to the instance or not (/dev/sdf).

I tried to do it in both ways but it keeps on telling me that the volume is not attached even though it is.

Here's my first attempt:

```
if test -d /dev/xvdf; then
    echo "Volume is attached!"
else
    echo "Volume is not attached! Please attach it first, then re-run this script!"
    exit 1
fi
```

And here's my second attempt:

```
if grep '/dev/xvdf' /etc/mtab > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Volume is attached!"
else
    echo "Volume is not attached!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Proof that the volume is attached here's `lsblk`'s output:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-XX-X-XX:~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0     8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0     8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0   100G  0 disk
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it also have to mounted first to something before checking? If so, is there a way check if the volume is attached without mounting it first?

Comment: test -d checks if a path is a directory, /dev/xvdf will be a block device not a directory. try `test -e` or `test -b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so, I've came up with a solution (not the prettiest solution of all, but it works)

```
vol='/dev/xvdf'
volcheck=`ls /dev/xvdf`

if [ $volcheck = $vol ]; then
        echo "Volume is attached!"
else
        echo "Volume isn't attached!"
fi
```

Also this works:

```
if test -b /dev/xvdf; then
    echo "Volume is attached!"
else
    echo "Volume is not attached! Please attach it first, then re-run this script!"
fi
```

Thanks to Douglas Leeder (from the comment above)!